# Pandas: Compare rows in a dataframe and adding values in new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in python and pandas. I am trying to solve a problem but everything I am trying, is failing.

I have a dataset which contains several columns as it shows below:

```
    id_trip     trip_schedule   start_longitude start_latitude
0   AAAAAAAA    1              -5.697868        42.393038
1   AAAAAAAA    2              -5.698459        42.394158
2   BBBBBBBB    1              -5.696362        42.398740
3   BBBBBBBB    2              -5.696071        42.401731
```

I would like to add two new columns stop_longitude and stop_latitude where as values they take the next row if id_trip is the same and trip_schedule start from 1.

The output should be as following:

```
id_trip   trip_schedule start_longitude start_latitude   stop_longitude   stop_latitude
0   AAAAAAAA    1              -5.697868        42.393038         -5.698459        42.394158
1   AAAAAAAA    2              -5.698459        42.394158         NaN              NaN
2   BBBBBBBB    1              -5.696362        42.398740         -5.696071        42.401731
3   BBBBBBBB    2              -5.696071        42.401731         NaN              NaN
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does your df include more trip_schedule? (Numbers higher than 2)

Otherwise, this should work just fine:

```
import pandas as pd 

dct = { 'id_trip': ['AAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBB', 'BBBBBBBB'],
        'trip_schedule': [1,2,1,2],
        'start_longitude': [-5.697868,-5.698459,-5.696362,-5.696071],
        'start_latitude': [42.393038,42.394158,42.398740,42.401731]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
df = df.sort_values(['id_trip', 'trip_schedule'])

df['stop_longitude'] = df.groupby(['id_trip'])['start_longitude'].shift(-1)
df['stop_latitude'] = df.groupby(['id_trip'])['start_longitude'].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
id_trip  trip_schedule  start_longitude  start_latitude  stop_longitude  \
0  AAAAAAAA              1        -5.697868       42.393038       -5.698459   
1  AAAAAAAA              2        -5.698459       42.394158             NaN   
2  BBBBBBBB              1        -5.696362       42.398740       -5.696071   
3  BBBBBBBB              2        -5.696071       42.401731             NaN   

   stop_latitude  
0      -5.698459  
1            NaN  
2      -5.696071  
3            NaN
```

Comment: No, the dataframe doesn't cotains any other trip_schedule. Your solution worked smoothly!!! thanx